# Unable to install, "no root file system is defined" 

Tags: installation, ubiquity, preseed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“No root file system defined” error while installing ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80455/no-root-file-system-defined-error-while-installing-ubuntu)

I am trying to feed the pressed to ubiquity while installing Xubuntu 11.10 .

Following is what I used in preseeding, and I used `debconf-set-selections` to set the below preseed.

```
ubiquity localechooser/preferred-locale select en_US.UTF-8
ubiquity debconf/language string en
ubiquity localechooser/languagelist select en
ubiquity debian-installer/language string en
ubiquity partman-auto/init_automatically_partition select 80custom__________custom
keyboard-configuration keyboard-configuration/unsupported_options boolean false
ubiquity partman/default_filesystem string ext4
ubiquity partman-auto/choose_recipe select myboot-root
ubiquity partman-auto/expert_recipe string \
myboot-root :: \
1 50 10240 ext4 \
$primary{ } $bootable{ } \
method{ format } format{ } \
use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
mountpoint{ / } \
. \
64 512 8172 linux-swap \
method{ swap } format{ } \
. \
500 10000 30720 ext4 \
method{ format } format{ } \
use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
mountpoint{ /backup_fs } \
. \
500 10000 10000000 ext4 \
method{ format } format{ } \
use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
mountpoint{ /home } \
.
ubiquity partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean false
ubiquity partman/choose_partition select finish
ubiquity partman/confirm boolean true
ubiquity partman-target/choose_method select 25filesystem__________ext4
```

And when I excute the ubiquity with `--automatic` option, it ends up with the error

> ```
> no root file system is defined
> ```

Below is the information for debugging purpose.