# "No root file system is defined" error during installation

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“No root file system defined” error while installing ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80455/no-root-file-system-defined-error-while-installing-ubuntu)

I tried installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32 bit, but when I get to this 
[image: step]

and hit forward I get taken to a prompt where it says "No root file system is defined." I don't even get to any part about partitioning, and there is nothing for me to choose or select from. Other similar posts at least get to a part where where they can choose how they want to allocate drive space.

I have followed the instructions for partitioning here:*http://members.iinet.net.au/~herman546/p22.html* **exactly** and my partition looks **exaclty** like 
[image: this]
 but I have more space. Everything is the same as this image (including partition names, file system names, and flags), except my sizes are bigger.

After this failed I deleted the new partitions, so I was left with dev/sda1 and dev/sda2, and tried to install again but I got the same error.

Every time I try out Ubuntu it's something new that seems to not work, and its super frustrating. Any help would be more than appreciated.