# Cannot Install Ubuntu 12.04: "Installation Type" screen has no options

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, system-installation

I am new to Ubuntu.
I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from USB key (in a dual-boot with Windows 7) and I have exactly the same problem with the blank "Installation Type" described here:

[Ubuntu 12.04 Install Problems.. Installation Type screen. No options](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170204/ubuntu-12-04-install-problems-installation-type-screen-no-options?lq=1)

I have followed the instructions in one of the comments, and giving the command

```
sudo apt-get remove dmraid
```

seems to solve the problem allowing me to see the partition.

**HOWEVER, I have not proceeded from here since I do not understand whether having removed this "dmraid" will give me problems afterwards, e.g. damaging my data or Ubuntu and/or Windows installation.**

Is "dmraid" something essential? Do I need to reinstall "dmraid" afterwards?

I would be really grateful if you could help me, I am very excited to try Ubuntu, but so far I have only had frustrations with the installation (I have also tried the Ubuntu Windows installer, getting exactly the same issue) and it took me some time to find the solution in the comments above.

Answer (score 4):

One possible root cause is that your computer uses Intel Smart Response Technology / Intel Rapid Storage Technology (ISRT / IRST), a kind of [RAID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID). It is somehow unusual or different compared to older versions of RAID, and dmraid doesn't understand it. Looking around, I see a few approaches that people have taken..

(1) The approach I recommend is to install mdadm, which is ([according to Intel](http://download.intel.com/design/intarch/PAPERS/326024.pdf)) the modern replacement of dmraid. When mdadm is available -- even if dmraid is also installed -- the ubuntu installation will use mdadm to correctly understand what the partitions are. At least it worked for me. [I posted details at another question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170204/ubuntu-12-04-install-problems-installation-type-screen-no-options/198004#198004)

(2) Another approach that many people have recommended is to turn off RAID altogether. This often involves changes in an Intel program that you run in Windows, and in BIOS. But the disc can still be left with RAID-type markings, and you have to run some commands to erase them before the disc is finally recognized as non-RAID ([explanation of this part](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9274738#post9274738)). For instructions in this method see [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2020155) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2038121). Turning off ISRT / IRST would presumably reduce performance somewhat. On the other hand, it seems from those pages that it is possible to resurrect RAID (at least in windows) to improve the performance after installing ubuntu. But I don't know, it seems to me that this approach leaves ubuntu ignorant of RAID while windows is using it, so I doubt ubuntu will be able to access files created in windows. I could be wrong.

(3) Finally, the approach you mention is to delete dmraid. I'm not sure exactly what happens here. Clearly it has worked for many people, although one can find [old reports](http://ryan.rawswift.com/2010/07/11/ubuntu-1004-lucid-lynx-installation-problems-no-partition-dmraid-library-error-and-blank-installation-window/) from people who had a bit more hassle than just that. One could also find a long time later that dmraid has reinstalled itself (as the dependency of something else), and I don't know whether that could cause problems. The most obvious problem, as before, is that it seems dangerous if windows is using ISRT but ubuntu knows nothing about RAID, yet you want ubuntu to be able to access the files created by windows. I could be wrong...

Answer (score 1):

What I did:

1. In the ubuntu search app I searched for "partition"
2. Opened "GParted"
3. "Device" --> "Create Partition"
4. Choose the device "sda" or "sdb" if you have two disks non-raid on your system
5. Choose "gpt" in the form that opens and that's it.
   repeat 4-5 for those disks you want to use for your linux installation

at this point the table will not be empty and you can continue as you wish

Comment: Thanks for this. I had the same problem installing 16.04 on an HDD that previously had Windows Server 2012 on it. I had to create a new partition table (msdos) on the drive in live-mode before installing.