# When installing installion type is blank (No options)

Tags: dual-boot, 13.10, system-installation

When i am trying to install Ubuntu it goes good int ill i get to the step Installation type step and when i am there i get no options and i know even before that i should get a option to duel boot and stuff like that but it did not show my that tab ether anyway when I am at installation type it gives me no options only but that works is quite or back.

I have read that its a problem with RAID but i do not know if i want to get rid of it i am kind of a noob at this stuff but i don't know if deleting is a good idea is there any other ways i can fix this problem

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I have a hard time understanding your question. That is what I **think** I understand: You'd like to install Ubuntu. You have already a OS installed and would like to install Ubuntu alongside. You have a RAID installation. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct

Comment: Could tell us what Ubuntu Version you are trying to install?

Comment: Latest version 13.10

Comment: Can you give us a bit more information how your RAID is setup?

Comment: Sorry im a beginner not to sure what u mean i heard raid was what my problem was but i do not know how to fix that this is the post i found       http://askubuntu.com/questions/170204/ubuntu-12-04-install-problems-installation-type-screen-no-options

Comment: My question is: Do you have RAID installed? If yes. In what way did you install RAID?

Comment: It came on my computer when i bought it

Comment: What is the make and model of your computer?