# Installing ubuntu 12.04.03

Tags: files, root, system

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my desktop and am getting the message: "no root file system is defined" on the menu for installation type. I can't seem to find what to do next.

Comment: sure duplicated http://askubuntu.com/q/135705/169736

Answer (score 0):

You have to label a partition as the root - "/". If you don't have experince with manual partitioning, try the automatic partitioning option.

[Here](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/installing) you got a install guide, just follow the steps

Comment: I have a new hard drive alongside my old one and I'm trying to install ubuntu in the new one. My corrupted Windows is in the old one. But I can't seem to find the button for automatic partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

Start to install Ubuntu and when it asks you if you want to replace or install next to or do something else, choose Do Something Else.
Then create the following partitions. 
1. a boot partition /boot and give it 250mb of space I would choose ext4 for the format 
2. a root partition /root and give it 12000mb space and ext4 format 
3. a swap partition /swap and give it 4096mb of space (it will format to swap) 
4  a home partition /home and give it the rest of the space and format it to ext4.
then continue your installtion.

Comment: OK, thanks. I have had a little luck in the last few minutes but I'll try yur specific suggestions. thanks again.