# I'm having problems with Ubuntu

Tags: grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Yesterday I tried to install Ubuntu.

I burned Ubuntu 10.04 Desktop on a CD, and it was really slow when I tried to boot from the CD.

So, I tried to install it from a USB-flash. I used Universal USB Installer and set it to my E:/ hard disk. Now, I can't load any system. Windows can't load I don't know why and Ubuntu can't to be installed. Because when I tried to install it to the hard drive, this message appears:

```
No root file system is defined

Please correct this from the partitioning menu..
```

What I must to do to recover Windows?

Comment: sorry for bad english. Im Ukrainian

Comment: choosing (vs. simply not knowing) to misspell words like "coz" (vs. "because") or starting the subject with "HEllo" will get you down-voted before your question is even read, regardless of the quality of the question.

Comment: Can you boot from the Live USB? I think, you really deleted and formatted your E:\ drive in the internel disk, unless your USB disk's drive letter is `E:`

Comment: To install Ubuntu, try http://askubuntu.com/a/137450/54298 and/or http://askubuntu.com/a/137379/54298. The first command is done on the live CD terminal before running Ubiquity(the installer).

Answer (score 0):

Booting Ubuntu from a live cd will indeed lag because you are running a whole operating system from a slow cd...  Usb flash drive is indeed a little quicker but booting from cd should gain you access to your hard-drive and let you backup any files that are important...

Comment: but I can't install any operating system on pc. Win detect hard problems Ubuntu detect... "No root file system is defined.". I can backup my files. But, what's next?

Comment: booting from a live cd doesn't install the OS, it runs the OS from the CD. Once you've booted from the live cd, copy files from the hard drive to some external backup disk (before it really is too late, if it isn't already too late)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Since thisdoes not directly answer the question, it is better suited as a comment. You can earn commenting privileges by earning reputation on the site.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have windows 7 back just run the windows 7 CD in repair mode.

follow this in order to have the console : http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/ss/windows-7-startup-repair.htm

Under the console you'll type :

```
fixboot
```

and

```
fixmbr
```

Those two commands will restore normaly the whole windows 7 boot process. if not follow the procedure of the link I gave you.

So now you are in single boot with windows 7.
For windows xp same procedure and go to the recovery mode then type `fixmbr` This should make your windows back to life.
If you have a mess with your partitions you can use the Gparted live cd to correct your partitions. 
To download Gparted live cd clicl [here](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php).

If you dont want to use **Gparted** you ca use a sofwtare caleed **Partition table doctor** for **Windows**