# unable to install Ubuntu12.10 on DELL inspiron 14z Ultrabook?

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“No root file system defined” error while installing ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80455/no-root-file-system-defined-error-while-installing-ubuntu)

I am unable to install Ubuntu12.10 on my DELL inspiron 14z Ultrabook??

when i tried, it is saying something like "root directory not defined"

Comment: Have you gone through this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/80455/no-root-file-system-defined-error-while-installing-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

What partitioning method are you using during the install? `Install alongside Windows` or `Something Else`.

If your using `Something Else` you need to set up the partitions like this:

- `Ext4` filesystem mounted as `/`. This will be your root directory. (15-20 GB should be plenty.)
- `Ext4` filesystem mounted as `/home`. This will be your home directory where all your documents, pictures, music etc. will be installed.
- `swap area` filesystem for the Swap partition (Once you select swap area the mount point option will be grayed out). (1GB should be more than enough seeing as the laptop has 6GB of RAM by default.