# No root file system

Tags: filesystem, root

I have almost the same problem with the link below.

["No root file system defined" error while installing ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80455/no-root-file-system-defined-error-while-installing-ubuntu?newreg=8ba556a154c4473abde3e28f84001155)

In my part, I had a problem with my drive about bitlocker key. I didnt have a chance to save the key then unfortuantely something happened in my laptop. So now I decided to change my OS from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 14.04.1.

While in the installing process "no root file system" window popped out, but the my situation is, I think ubuntu doesn't read my HDD.

Here are the screen pictures,
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Warning: this will erase your data!

You might be able to erase the bitlocked partitions using gparted. Start the live disk and choose "try ubuntu without installing".

Then, search for the application gparted. Gparted should list the bitlocked partition(s). You should have the option to delete these partitions. You must click the check mark icon to "apply" these changes.

You might want to go ahead and reformat the drive to ext4 while you are at it. Proceed with installation when you are done.

see: [how-to-format-a-drive-encrypted-with-bitlocker](https://superuser.com/questions/408809/how-to-format-a-drive-encrypted-with-bitlocker)

and: [wipe-delete-and-securely-destroy-your-hard-drives-data-the-easy-way](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15817/wipe-delete-and-securely-destroy-your-hard-drives-data-the-easy-way/)