# problem whle installing ubuntu

Tags: 14.10, files, root

I am trying to install ubuntu from the hard drive.When the home screen appears after restarting the computer a message says that "No root file system is defined"(as superuser).I partitioned my hardisk and still its showing the same problem.Please anyone give me a solution

Answer (score 0):

That may be because you have not assigned the filesystem type (ext4).
Maybe this question can also help you => ["No root file system defined" error while installing ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80455/no-root-file-system-defined-error-while-installing-ubuntu)