# No disk, no partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, disk

Okay guys, I had a bit of a problem with my PC earlier. Not sure what happened, it just crashed in the middle of me playing a game and when I restarted it's now telling me I have no operating system or hard disk.

Luckily I have a USB I can use to boot Ubuntu. However, even that is giving me problems. I try to install, but it gives me the "No root file system is defined" error message. But there's no option to create or select a partition, the table is just empty. When I click the 'change' button it just crashes out and takes me to the Live Ubuntu (the trial version, basically, where you can't keep any files because they will all be gone when you restart.)

Is there anything I can do? I really can't afford a new computer.

Comment: Boot up using the USB and open the application Gparted. Then, what does it say?

Comment: It certainly looks like your computer is not broken but you may just need a new hard drive but even that may still be good, we shall see. Did  you set the partition to format ext4? Did you set the mount point to `/`? Does gparted show a device /dev/sda?

Comment: Also, have you checked out http://askubuntu.com/questions/80455/no-root-file-system-defined-error-while-installing-ubuntu?